# Filter in qlikview?

Tags: qlikview

I want to make a filter in Qlikview but I want to choose some data in that filter not the all,

Can you help me please.

Help is appreciated

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand your question. Maybe some example data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to display part of a data set in a filter, i.e

if you have the field "**Year**" and the dataset is:

```
2012
2013
2014
2015
```

and you want to display **only values larger than 2013** in a filter, then you should create a "**listbox**" and choose "**expression**" in the drop down field picker.

The expression then should be 
`if(Year>2013,Year)`.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use set analysis in the expresion associated to that element.

For example:

= Sum({$} intr.num_c_ggs_cr_00360)/1000000

With this set analysis your filter by divisa, some contrapartidas (App, Brg....) and the you do the sum of all num value that matches that filter.

PD: never use if because is bad for your aplication, set analysis is always faster.

Answer (score 0):

For List Box sheet objects, we have Expressions tab. If we have Salary as a field and we want the name whose salary is greater than 30000.

Below is the expression we can set in Expressions tab by selecting conditional radio button:

if(salary > 30000)

Hope this helps